# Store TensorFlow Models in Browser

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

So, on my website, I use [TensorFlow pre-built models](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/models). The problem is, these models take a few seconds to load and reduce user experience.

Usually, you could save and load these models with https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/save_load, but this pre-built model doesn't seem to have any built-in saving capabilities.

(Apparently, after loading a model for the first time, thatmodel.model will give the actual model, but not with the easy to use functions such as ".classify").

Is there any way to work around that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What model are you looking to use in the browser?

Comment: I want to use the natural language question answering models.

Comment: When are you loading in the model? Ideally you should load it directly after calling `tf.ready()` and in my experience these models load instantly. Other than that you could download the model and then convert it to the appropriate format to be loaded directly in the browser but warning it could be really big and be even slower than what you are currently trying even with quantization applied.

Comment: Well the documentation https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/qna#api simply says to do ```qna.load``` and nothing about tensorflow...

Comment: Does my answer solve it?

Comment: Well, I'm trying not to have to use a backend, and where do I even insert the model? For example, what goes into the main() function?

Comment: It's not a backend as in communicating with the server, it just allows the models you use to run faster, there is a link in the answer with more information. Nothing goes into it you just set it as I did and run your model as usual.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [WebGL backend](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/03/introducing-webassembly-backend-for-tensorflow-js.html) which should speed up the inference times compared to the Plain JS backend.

```
<!-- Import @tensorflow/tfjs or @tensorflow/tfjs-core -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>
 
<!-- Adds the WASM backend to the global backend registry -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-wasm/dist/tf-backend-wasm.js"></script>
 
<script>
  tf.setBackend('wasm').then(() => main());
</script>
```